# Datetime picker doesn't appear in Internet Explorer and FireFox with Bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a datetime picker in my view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.EventDate, new
    {htmlAttributes = new {
            @Value = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString(),
            @class = "form-control datepicker" }, })
```

I've dropped the `css`files in the directory `Content` in my project:

[image]

It is `Twitter Bootstrap` **v3.0.1**

And my scripts in the directory `Scripts`:

[image]

Here's my `_Layout.cshtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    @RenderSection("meta", required: false)
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- ... -->
    <link href="~/Content/themes/flatly/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
          rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- ... -->

    @Scripts.Render("~/js")    
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my Model

```
public class MyModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EventDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

When I execute the web site, the rendering is different on `IE` or `Chrome`

**On chrome**

[image: On Chrome]

**On IE**

[image]

**On FireFox**

[image]

**How to I manage the datetime picker on `IE` and `FireFox`?**

Comment: It appears your using the browsers HTML5 datepicker (does your property `EventDate` have `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`? (and NEVER override the `value` attribute like that when using a html helper)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: Yes it has `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` (see update).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Stephen Muecke pointed the reason of the problem:

> [Refer comparision here](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome-39/firefox-38/opera-24/ie-11.html). The type="date" attribute is not supported in either IE-11 or FireFox-38 so you're out of luck for the time being.

The solution I've emplemented  to use HTML5 datepicker when exists or use the JQuery datepicker when it doesn't is this one:

In `_Layout.cshtml` I checked this line existed and `modernizr` was installed in my solution (which should be the case by default)

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

In the view with the datepicker, in the `@section Scripts` I added

```
@section Scripts {
    /* ... */
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* ... */
        if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();
        }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue as nothing to do with bootstrap. Your rendering the browsers HTML5 datepicker which required the format to be `yyyy-MM-dd` (ISO format)

Include the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute on your property

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
```

and in the view, use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.EventDate, new
{
  htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" }
})
```

Note you should never override the `value` attribute when using a html helper (consider what happens if a user enters a date which is not todays date and submits, but because of a `ModelState` error you need to return the view for correction - your code would reset the users selection back to today's date)

Comment: I did, but nothing changed. As a side note, the date is a subproperty of the Model. in the cshtml, it is `Model.Event.EventDate`. I also decorated the property with `DisplayAttribute` and `RequiredAttribute`

Comment: Also just noticed this is tagged mvc-4, but you cannot add html attributes using the `EditorFor()` method - you need at least mvc-5.1 - which are you using?

Comment: If its `Model.Event.EventDate` then the helper would need to be `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Event.EventDate, ....)`

Comment: IT seems to be 5 as my web.config shows `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />` for System.Web.Mvc.

Comment: Yes, that is MVC-5 - I will edit the tags. Also, ensure you set the value in the controller before you pass the model to the view - `model.Event.EventDate = DateTime.Today;`

Comment: The model is set, it is displayed in the textbox in the view but still no datetime picker in IE...

Comment: Firstly, is the issue not fixed in `Chrome` - i.e. correctly displaying today's date instead of `mm/dd/yyyy`? Next, which versions of IE and FireFox are you using - the HTML5 datepickers are only supported in recent versions (and in fact I thought they were not yet implemented in FireFox at all yet)

Comment: The issue never appeared in `Chrome`. It only exists in `IE` v11.0  and `FireFox` v38.05

Comment: The issue does appear in Chrome - your screen shot clearly show the value `mm/dd/yyyy` when it should be `28-06-2015`. Let me check if which versions support `type="date"`

Comment: [Refer comparision here](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome-39/firefox-38/opera-24/ie-11.html). The `type="date"` attribute is not supported in either IE-11 or FireFox-38 so your out of luck for the time being.

Comment: Use the jquery.ui datepicker or similar jquery plugin (gives you lots more options anyway)